# Qt scene->addItem doesn't display QGraphicsPixmapItem

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsscene

Below is my code for adding a bitmap file to scene by pressing a pushbutton. I can add an ellipse by scene->addEllipse but i cannot add/display Menu1.bmp by scene->addItem. As you see, either of them are in same function. Also in run mode, as i push the button, i get "item has already been added to this scene" warning. Why i cannot see the item if it has been added, any help?

.h file

```
#include <QWidget>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QGraphicsItem>

namespace Ui {
class Widget;
}

class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Widget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Widget();

private slots:
    void changeMenu();

private:
    Ui::Widget *ui;

    QGraphicsScene *scene;
    QGraphicsView *view;
    QPushButton *menu;
    QGraphicsPixmapItem *newItem;
};
```

.cpp file

```
    #include "widget.h"
    #include "ui_widget.h"
    #include <QLayout>
    #include <QPixmap>

    Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
        QWidget(parent),
        ui(new Ui::Widget)
    {
        ui->setupUi(this);

        scene = new QGraphicsScene(0, 0, 100, 100);
        view->setScene(scene);

        newItem=new QGraphicsPixmapItem(QPixmap(":/images/Menu1.bmp"));

        QHBoxLayout *labelLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
        menu = new QPushButton;
        menu->setText(tr("Menu"));        
        labelLayout->addWidget(view);
        labelLayout->addWidget(menu);
        connect(menu, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(changeMenu()));
        setLayout(labelLayout);
    }

    void Widget::changeMenu()
    {
        if(!QPixmap(":/images/Menu1.bmp").isNull())
            scene->addEllipse(-10,-10,10,10);
        else
            scene->addEllipse(10,-100,10,100);
        scene->addItem(newItem);
    }
```

main.cpp file

```
#include "widget.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Widget w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: make sure that the `Menu1.bmp` exists and can be loaded and displayed correct, set it as background of a `QLabel` just to check that

Comment: I have just tested your almost exact code with my image and it works, so it's likely that the problem is the image itself.

Comment: @Zaiborg Thank u for make me focusing correct issue. It is all about resource file.